# Spanning the space of holomorphic $L^1$ functions by rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half plane. Consider the Banach space $X$ of holomorphic $L^1$ functions on $\mathbb{H}$. For $a,b,c\in-\mathbb{H}$ (lower half plane), write $$f_{a,b,c}(z)=\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)}.$$ It is clear that $f_{a,b,c}\in X$. My question is whether the linear subspace spanned by these functions is $L^1$-dense in $X$, or at least weakly dense, i.e., if $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{H})$ is such that $\int_{\mathbb{H}}f_{a,b,c}g=0$ for all $a,b,c\in-\mathbb{H}$, then $\int_{\mathbb{H}}fg=0$ for all $f\in X$.

It is not hard to show that they are indeed $L^2$-dense in the space of holomorphic $L^2$ functions by computing the Bergmann kernel, but for $L^1$ no such tool is available.

Comment: Can u approximate $e^{-\gamma z}$ by span of $f_{a,b,c}(z)$ ?

Comment: @Balajisb I don't think it's $L^1$. What $\gamma$ do you take?

Comment: I typed your question in https://poe.com/Sage . It is giving some inputs. Check it out.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of the density of the space $f_{a,b,c}$ assuming monotonic Riemann sums w.r.t modulus:

For $|z| < r$ and $|\gamma(t)|\leq r$, $$f(z) = \int_{0}^1 \frac{f(\gamma(t))}{\gamma(t)-z} \gamma'(t) dt$$
For $|z|>r$ and $|\gamma(t)|\leq r$, $$0 = \int_{0}^1 \frac{f(\gamma(t))}{\gamma(t)-z} \gamma'(t) dt$$

Hence $$f_{approx}(z) = \int_{0}^1 \frac{f(\gamma(t))}{\gamma(t)-z} \gamma'(t) dt$$ is an $L^1$ approximation to $f(z)$ for properly chosen $\gamma$.

$\int_{0}^1 \frac{f(\gamma(t))}{\gamma(t)-z} \gamma'(t) dt$ can be approximated by Riemann sums (which is a rational function):
$$f_{rs,N}(z) = \sup_{s_m \in [m-1/N,m/N] \text{ w.r.t modulus $|f_{rs,N}(z)|$ }} 
 \sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{f(\gamma(s_n))}{\gamma(s_n)-z} \gamma'(s_n) \frac{1}{N}$$

We can conclude the proof by monotone convergence theorem if we can show that atleast one of the Riemann sum $f_{rs,m}(z)$ for some $m$ is $L^1$ since $|f_{rs,n}(z)|  \geq |f_{rs,2n}(z)|$.

Since $|f_{rs,m}(z)| \geq |f_{rs,2m}(z)|$, we have by dominated convergence theorem, $$||f-f_{rs,n}||_{L^1} \leq ||f-f_{approx}||_{L^1}  + ||f_{approx}-f_{rs,n}||_{L^1} \leq \int_{|z|>r} |f(z)| + \epsilon \leq 2 \epsilon $$. So proof is done if we have that $f_{rs,m}$ is $L^1$ for some $m$.

Final piece of the puzzle: Show atleast for one $m$, $f_{rs,m}$ is $L^1$ OR Modify the definition of $f_{rs,n}$ and prove that $|f_{rs,n}(z)| \leq |f_{rs,2n}(z)|$.

EDIT:
Except for a small compact set around $\gamma$, we have uniform convergence of $f_{rs,n}$ to $f_{approx}$.

We can convert a uniform convergence to an $L^1$ convergence here by multiplying with $$g_n(z) = \frac{1}{(1-\frac{iz}{n})^k}$$.

Let $W(z) \in L^1$, then, $$f_n(z) = g_n(z)W(z),$$ $$\int_{\mathbb{H}} |g_n(z)| |W(z)| \leq \int |W(z)| < \infty$$. Hence $g_n(z)W(z)$ is in $L^1$ and $$|g_n(z)W(z)| \geq |g_{n+1}(z)W(z)|, \lim_n g_n(z)W(z) \rightarrow W(z)$$.

Hence we have $g_n(z)W(z) \rightarrow W(z)$ in $L^1$ by dominated convergence theorem.

We set $Q_{n}(z) = g_n(z)f_{approx}(z)$ and Let $T_{n}(z) = g_n(z)f_{rs,n}(z)$, we have $|T_{n}(z)| = |g_n(z)f_{rs,n}(z)| \geq |T_{2n}(z)| = |g_{2n}(z)f_{rs,2n}(z)|$. We also have $T_{n}(z)$ in $L^1$.

Hence $Q_n(z) \rightarrow f_{approx}(z)$ by dominated convergence theorem and $T_n(z), Q_n(z)$ converges to same limit by uniform convergence of $f_{rs,n}$ to $f_{approx}$ (except for a compact set around $\gamma$) and the fact $g_n(z)$ is in $L^1$. We already have that $f_{approx}(z) \rightarrow f(z)$ in $L^1$.

So except for a small compact set around $\gamma$ which changes with definition of $f_{approx}$, we have proved that $f(z)$, an $L^1$ holomorphic function, can be approximated by rational functions $T_n(z)$.

The size of this compact set can be made as small as possible. There are poles on $\gamma$ for the rational functions $T_n(z)$. This is the reason for leaving out this compact set.

Comment: I don't want to sound too pessimistic, but I don't see how you can make an approximation on compact sets and then an approximation on the rest. The functions are holomorphic, if we fix them on a small ball, you have no freedom how to extend, right? Do you have any intuition on what might help us?

Comment: $\int |f_{approx}(z) - f(z)| dz \leq \epsilon \mu(K) + \int_{|z| >r} |f_{approx}(z)| dz+ \int_{|z| >r}  |f(z)| dz \leq \epsilon \mu(K)  + \epsilon + \epsilon$, if $f_{approx}(z)$ is $L^1$ and tail integrates to $\epsilon$ on $|z|>r$ and $|f_{approx}(z)-f(z)| \leq \epsilon$ in compact set $K$. This is what i had in mind. In point 4) we can see that $\int_{\text{Outside } \gamma} |f_{approx} - f(z)| =\int_{\text{Outside } \gamma} |f(z)| \leq \epsilon$ since $f(z)$ is $L^1$. So these are the points i had in mind. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the reason in point 4) $f_{approx}(z)  = \int_{0}^1 \frac{f(\gamma(t))}{\gamma(t)-z} \gamma'(t) dt$ is an $L^1$ approximation. Because $f_{approx}(z) = 0$ outside $\gamma$ and $\int_{\text{outside $\gamma$ }} |f_{approx}(z) - f(z)| = \int_{\text{outside $\gamma$ }} |f(z)| < \epsilon$ since $f$ is $L^1$. Inside $\gamma$,  the approximation is uniform.

Comment: So the job is to show Riemann sum mentioned in my answer is an $L^1$ approximation to $f_{approx}(z) = \int_{0}^1 \frac{f(\gamma(t))}{\gamma(t)-z} \gamma'(t) dt$ w.r.t $z$.

Comment: In fact if you show Riemann sum is $L^1$ then by dominated convergence theorem we have the result that these Riemann sums are $L^1$ approximation. So all we need to show these Riemann sums are $L^1$.

Comment: Infact i am wondering if we can conclude the proof by monotone convergence theorem since Riemann sums are monotonic if we take lower sums.

Comment: I edited answer again. Please check it out and let me know.

Comment: I think my concern is that if you invoke any approximation on compact set, it seems unlikely that you have any control on the $L^1$ tail of the approximation. Most of the arguments are not constructive and it seems difficult to translate this into a global approximation in $L^1$. Of course, if you can do that, then you are done, but that is essentially what we want to prove, right?

Comment: Hi i gave a clear argument in point 4). There is only one point missing in the derivation in point 4). Check it out and give me your feedback. The argument in point 4) follows from point 3) since the approximation i am giving also works over compact set enclosed by $\gamma$.

Comment: I removed non-constructive statements and retained only concrete proof. Let me know on what you think. One point still missing in the derivation.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check it out.